# What is the need for creating custom xpaths ?

Tags: java, selenium

firepath already provides absolute path, relative path.So, what's the need for creating custom xpaths ?

Comment: What do you mean with custom xpaths?

Comment: Relative xpath for "Add comment" object in this page is .//*[@id='add-comment-34248560']/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/input.Custom Xpath is  //*[@input='submit' and @value='Add Comment'] .What is the use of this custom xpath when both relative & custom xpath serve the same purpose?

Answer (score 0):

XPath is a descriptor, absolut means it describes a node from the root element down the tree to the leaf you want to find.
Relative means that the descriptor starts at a node you choose inside the tree and goes to the node you want.

In you example for custom node it's just another filter. First one filters on the id attribute which should be unique and the second is a bit wrong but what you meant is probably a node with name input that has the attributes type=submit and value='Add Comment'.